# Which ip from dns round robin I am querying to?

Tags: curl, dns, ip

There is multiple IP addresses assigned to same domain name with DNS round robin.

Can I guess which one I am using when doing a query to specific domain?

Can I enforce usage as single ip from a list for given request using curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [--resolve](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) to forcibly set an IP address to a given name+port combo.

Answer (score 0):

or use the host file , but to see what IP you are hitting just use  curl -v http://foo.bar

"-v" option will show you much more information together with the IP address you are actually hitting